# Slide divs in single row

Tags: jquery, css

How to make divs slide  in single row on button left/right click?
Something like [this](http://coffeescripter.com/code/ad-gallery/#ad-image-0) bottom part of a gallery

this is my attempt in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elementhttp/PJxV9/)

```
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
    $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
    });
    $( "#left" ).click(function(){
    $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
    });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PJxV9/1/)**.

Instead of `left` property try with `scrollLeft`:

```
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
    $( ".box" ).animate({
        scrollLeft: '+=' + $( ".box" ).width()
    });
});
$( "#left" ).click(function(){
    $( ".box" ).animate({
        scrollLeft: '-=' + $( ".box" ).width()
    });
});
```

That gives you the great advantage that you don't need to check if the boxes will go *over* the maximum allowed position.

You will also need to modify CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.block {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #abc;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Most important thing here (essential for the mechanism to work), are `overflow: hidden`, `white-space: nowrap` in `.box` class and `display: inline-block` in `.block` class.